# Heapsize problem on VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, governorlimits, pagereference, largedatavolumes

I am VF page which display records for a custom object. When there are a large number of custom records - I get: `HEAPSIZE 6014176 error on page.`

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're retrieving too much data and running into an Apex [governor limit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm). You will need to reduce the amount of data you're retrieving and working with.

**Update**

One way to deal with this is to paginate the records returned. Salesforce provides a [StandardSetController](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) that allows you to easily work with lists and paginated results; in short you can create your own list view with it.

Comment: thanks but is there a kinda of a "more" button I can get out to limit the size displayed at any one time.

Comment: I've updated my answer.